# Apache POI make rounds on numeric values it reads?

Tags: apache, apache-poi, rounding

I use apache poi 3.10-FINAL and I get a very strange behaviour when reading numbers from an excel sheet : indeed, the result of cell.getNumericCellValue() on 0.001306 is not 0.001306 but : 0.0013059999999 (!). And 2587441349.95676 becomes 2.5874413499567585E9.

I tried many different things, like changing the type of the cell to "String" before reading it (anyway, numeric values are changed into string values immediatly after reading...), or using the getRawValue() methode but if the value is the good one, the format is not : 0.001306 becomes 1.306E-3, and I can't apply formatting rules since there is no real formatting rule, the only rule is : it must be like it was in the excel sheet (one value can be 00.001306, the other one can be 1.306E-3...)

I tried to make changes in the excel sheet, with the "format cell" button, but it doesn't change anything.The only case where those numeric data are considered as string values is when a put un simple quote in front of the number.

And... I don't understand why, but it seems I'm the only one to meet such problem on earth...?

(Sorry for my poor english...)

Comment: Welcome to the [wonderful world of Floating Point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)! What happens if you try using [DataFormatter.formatCellValue](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29) on the cell, does that give the answer you expected?

Answer (score 3):

Promoting a comment to an answer

Welcome to the [wonderful world of Floating Point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)! Excel `.xlsx` files always store their numbers as string representations of floating point numbers, and `.xls` does in almost all cases, even for simple integer values.

By default, Apache POI will give you back the value that is stored in the file. Where the value isn't exact in a decimal floating point representation, like your case, you'll get back that not-quite-exact value just as is in the file.

However, if what you want is "a string that looks like what Excel displays for that cell", then Apache POI has a handy utility method that does the rounding / formatting for you, based on the formatting rules applied to the cell. That class is [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html), and the method you'll want is [DataFormatter.formatCellValue(Cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29)